# Modular Contracts with Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

we have the Problem, that we have to use parts of a contract in several project. Is there the possibility to split contracts into several fragments and include this parts into every contracts who needs it in there structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the DSL (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/multi/multi__customization.html#_common_jar). Create a separate project with the common piece of DSL and then reuse it in any contract you need.

Comment: Thank you, I already saw that doc. The examples are more like "utils".
Would it be possible to write an "include" like function where I include another dsl file?

Like:

    myblock: [
    $(MyUtils.include('mypart.groovy'))
    ]

Comment: Everything is possible but that sounds like a terrible idea. You should keep your contracts simple

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the structure of the data but have to test some parts of the api. Some substructure is owned by another team, so I just could use a par of their contracts.
Without an import mechanism I have to keep them in sync myself